# does anyone perform "build" operation for website project

Tags: build

I have read about the difference between website project and web application project. I have never created any web application, and I just managed to create a basic web site project recently.

I would like to ask -- Does it make sense for me to do "build" on my web site project or it is totally stupid for me to do so? If it make sense then what does it really do to my web site project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this just a static web site? (No database, server side code, api's, file concatenation, preprocessors, data transactions, etc) If not (or none of those words sound familiar), then you shouldn't need a build process.

Its the web applications with user interactions that involve data manipulations and several different user states that need some some sort of testing that mocks up these user actions and test code validation through different scenarios. This is especially the case the more complex your application gets and/or the more developers that get involved.

You can check out a pretty in depth explanation from [pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/build-process-workflows-tooling-gruntjs), or a nice read from [David Tucker](http://davidtucker.net/articles/automating-with-grunt/) that involves a static site use case.

This build process is basically going to run through all the tasks that you have defined in the 'build process'. These tasks can be practically anything but often include testing, performance tasks like file compression etc. Perhaps a good explanation of handling a smaller (static) sites is that you could just do any of theses steps in a manual process if need be.

Comment: The web site project that I have does link and do data transaction with Microsoft SQL server. It also has server side codes as well as client side codes. However, we do not have any intention to change it to web application.

Comment: Nathan, looks like the reference that you pointed me to is dealing with something called GRUNT which I am not familiar with... yet. Because the site that I build is server within company intranet, so I don't think I can use the GRUNT, but we do have Team Foundation Server.